# Copy Chrome extension and it's data to another chrome application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

i.e. This extension, [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl), has a function to export links of open tabs, however not import them. This would make a hassle of opening individual links of each exported tabs to "import" them to the new destination (Computer to Computer)

I figure that I could just copy the extension and it's files over instead of going through the hassle, but this doesn't work.

I've located the extension's ID and folder, and I've copied over to another chrome browser. (which has an unused Tabs Outliner waiting to be replaced with a new one) And upon opening the browser, expecting Tabs to transfer, but it remained unchanged.

Is there some data files that I missed that were needed to copy the data over?

Chrome's Sync ability only syncs the extensions, Themes and bookmarks, not any data/changes made to the extensions. So this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry if this is vague, but get Tabs outliner and use it for a while, then try to copy the extension to another Chrome browser (on another computer, OS, etc) and you will understand.

Comment: Old TO/Old Chrome > Old TO/New Chrome = Result: New TO on New Chrome

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your actual question (How do I copy all tabs from one Chrome instance to another?) is different from your posted question. I'm assuming your actual question is the one you want answered.

Chrome can sync open tabs. Setting this up is [described here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582). I believe it requires that the source machine is online and ready to go at the same time the destination machine is online.

If it's not the case that both machines can be active, there's another option. On the source machine, open the menu (the hamburger in the upper right) and select "Bookmarks". Under the "Bookmarks" menu is an item "Bookmark open pages...". Clicking this opens a dialog allowing you to create a bookmark folder containing links for all your open tabs. Synchronize your bookmarks as usual. On the destination machine, navigate to "Bookmarks" as before. The folder you created should be in there. Right-click this folder and select "Open all bookmarks".